# Display a D3 chart inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, xmlhttprequest

**Situation :** I have a simple web-page with some form data and a submit button.

Earlier, on clicking the button the page used to redirect to another page, where the D3 chart was drawn. So far, so good.

Now, I want to draw this chart on a div within the same page. For this, I send an xmlHTTP request (to a PHP controller inside an MVC framework).

But the d3 chart is not displayed, and I get a very mangled html. How to solve this issue ?

Code:

```
function loadXMLDoc(newUrl)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("output").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
//xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford",true);

alert('Sending xmlHttp request');
//var url = window.location.pathname + '?q=' + "http://localhost/parentsconcernV2/index.php/analytics_storytrend/index/253/0/0/177";

xmlhttp.open("GET",newUrl,true);


xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `d3.xml`?

Comment: So in your code you are just setting the innerHTML to whatever you get from the request. This is a bit confusing. Are you actually using d3 somewhere? To figure out what is wrong check the response of the request and the stuff which is in your DOM afterwards.

Comment: Lars, no idea about that.

nothing9, that's correct I'm trying to display the page using innerHTML. The requested page has the D3 chart. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: One more thing! In the response you are getting: is it just static HTML or is there javascript inside? Because the scripts will not be executed if you just attach the contents to your dom.

Comment: Well yes, it has a very large executing script that accepts parameters and draws the chart.....In that case, I'll just try to draw the chart in the same page inside a div.

Comment: Another option for you might be an iframe (even though a lot of people consider them to be evil). You can load pages into them like it was a separate browser-window. And if you come to a point where you also think that iframes are evil I can recommend require.js for content loading.

Comment: OK. I'll may try those, if drawing the chart inside the div (using all the horrendous scripts) doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestions, especially that scripts aren't executed if we merely attach the contents. That's mainly where I was going wrong.